# selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSessionIdException: Message: invalid session id

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Как победить? 
driver.close(), driver.quit() не помогает

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56492149/5909792

Answer (score 1):

возможно у тебя после того как отрабатывает driver.close() выполняется еще какой-то метод driver.какой-то_метод(). Объекта driver уже нет, а ты пытаешься что-то выполнить, отсюда и invalid session id.

Answer (score 0):

```
    from selenium.common.exceptions import InvalidSessionIdException

    try
        #do staff
    except InvalidSessionIdException:
        print('FAIL')
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]